# oracle -rearrange columns values based on value type

Tags: oracle

I have three oracle tables :

```
table_1:
ID   some_fields
121      xx
122      xx
123      xx
124      xx
125      xx

create table table_1 as
select 121 id ,'xx' some_fields from dual
union select 122 id,'xx' some_fields from dual
union select 123 id,'xx' some_fields from dual
union select 124 id,'xx' some_fields from dual
union select 125 id,'xx' some_fields from dual


table_2:
ID   some_fields
221      xx
222      xx
223      xx
224      xx
225      xx

create table table_2 as
select 221 id,'xx' some_fields from dual
union select 222 id,'xx 'some_fields from dual
union select 223 id,'xx' some_fields from dual
union select 224 id,'xx' some_fields from dual
union select 225 id,'xx' some_fields from dual

table3:
ID    field_1    field_2
1      121         221
2      222         125
3      225         124
4      123         223
5      122         224

create table table_3 as
select 1 id, 121 field_1,221 field_2 from dual
union select 2 id, 222 field_1,125 field_2 from dual
union select 3 id, 225 field_1,124 field_2 from dual
union select 4 id, 123 field_1,223 field_2 from dual
union select 5 id, 122 field_1,224 field_2 from dual
```

I need to re-arrange table_3 to have all ids of table_1 in field_1 and all ids of table_2 in field_2 , knowing that ids in table_1 and table_2 are unique.

```
ID    field_1    field_2
1      121         221
2      125         222
3      124         225
4      123         223
5      122         224
```

Noting in reality that these tables contain millions of rows.
I'm thinking of creating a view that accomplish my need but not sure how to proceed.

Comment: What do you mean by "all ids of table_1 in field_1 and all ids of table_2 in field_2"? What is the relationship between table_1 and table_2 that you are representing here? Does id_of_type_1 = id_of_type_2, or is this a cartesian relationship where every id of table_1 is associated with every id of table_2?

Comment: there is no relationship between table_1 and table_2. table_3 contains values of table_1 and table_2 , where I need to arrange them to have all values belonging to table_1 in field_1 and the values belonging to table_2 in field_2

Comment: you are effectively creating a many-to-many relationship with table_3. which value from table_1 should be in the same row with which value from table_2, or should every value from one table map to every value of the other? It would help if you could give a more specific example - with actual data values - for us to know what you're trying to do.

Comment: no actually I'm not populating table_3 based on data from table_1 and table_2. table_3 is already there and contains values from table_1 and table_2 in field_1 and field_2, and I want to re-arrange it as I described.

Comment: Can you provide sample DDL and some DML to populate the tables. This looks like a strange data modelling approach.

Comment: @DomG I edited the example in the question to make it clear

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, then according to your example, column FIELD_1 in TABLE_3 must contain only values from column ID in TABLE_1. Likewise, column FIELD_2 in TABLE_3 must contain only ID values from TABLE_2.

In your sample data, there are some values from TABLE_2 in column FIELD_1 and you want to update TABLE_3 so that only IDs from TABLE_1 appear in column FIELD_1 in TABLE_3.

If the above explanation is correct, then the following SQL will fix that:

```sql
update TABLE_3
   set FIELD_1 = FIELD_2
      ,FIELD_2 = FIELD_1
 where not exists (select 1 from TABLE_1 where TABLE_1.ID = TABLE_3.FIELD_1);
```

### EDIT

(Due to your first [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61817437/oracle-rearrange-columns-values-based-on-value-type/61820307#comment109345793_61820307).)

The following SQL query produces your desired result.

```sql
select T3.ID
      ,(select T1.ID from TABLE_1 T1 where T1.ID = T3.FIELD_1 or T1.ID = T3.FIELD_2) as FIELD_1
      ,(select T2.ID from TABLE_2 T2 where T2.ID = T3.FIELD_2 or T2.ID = T3.FIELD_1) as FIELD_2
  from TABLE_3 T3
```

### EDIT 2

(Due to your second [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61817437/oracle-rearrange-columns-values-based-on-value-type/61820307#comment109347103_61820307).)

Using joins.

```sql
select T3.ID
      ,T1.ID as FLD_1
      ,T2.ID as FLD_2
  from TABLE_3 T3
  join TABLE_2 T2 on (T2.ID = T3.FIELD_1 or T2.ID = T3.FIELD_2)
  join TABLE_1 T1 on (T1.ID = T3.FIELD_1 or T1.ID = T3.FIELD_2)
```

Comment: I dont want to update table_3 , I just want to create a view that have the result I need.

Comment: but assuming the 3 tables contain millions of record, the query you provided will take a considerable time. how can I fetch the desired result in the fastest time?

Comment: I don't think the role of stack overflow is to optimise code for you. If you have a further question I think it's probably better to ask that in a new submission. You are now stating you think it will perform poorly with out any facts. @abra supplied an answer to your question. Please accept it an answer.